# (Shiny) Modify table filtered by the user and see it reflected in the main table

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, dt

I have relied on the following [Code](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/480) so that the user can modify the shiny table.
I have a large database, before the user modifies the table I would like him to be able to filter by "material" and then he can make the corresponding modifications, especially the column "stockobj", then I would like to see the filtered table and the main table with the modifications that were made previously.
As you can see in the picture: [App][https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ecpK.png]

My code:

````
library(DT)

df<- tibble(material=c(12345,12345,12345,12345,12345, 67891,67891,67891,67891,67891),
            centro=c("H01", "H02", "H03", "H04","H05","H01", "H02", "H03",  "H04","H05" ),
            rotaSem= c(0.66,0.55,0.43,0.45, 0.33, 0.34,0.78, 0.31,0.89,0.87),
            stockobj=c(1,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,1))


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("My app"),
    selectInput("mate", "Select material", choices = unique(df$material)),
    h3("Edit table"),
    DTOutput('x1'),
    h3("Main table"),
    DTOutput("x2")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    x = df

  
    categ<-reactive({
      x %>% filter(material==input$mate)
    })
    
    output$x1 <- renderDT(categ(), selection = 'none', rownames = F, editable = T)
    output$x2 <- renderDT({
      x
    })
    
    
    proxy = dataTableProxy('x1')
    
    observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {
      
      info = input$x1_cell_edit
      str(info)
      i = info$row
      j = info$col + 1  # column index offset by 1
      v = info$value
      x[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, x[i, j])
      replaceData(proxy, x, resetPaging = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
    })
  }
)```

I have been looking for a solution for several days but I have not been able to. The problem is that to modify the table I have to modify the "reactive" and I don't think it is possible. Any ideas?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ecpK.png
````

Comment: Please use `reactiveValues` object instead of reactive object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

df<- data.frame(material=c(12345,12345,12345,12345,12345, 67891,67891,67891,67891,67891),
            centro=c("H01", "H02", "H03", "H04","H05","H01", "H02", "H03",  "H04","H05" ),
            rotaSem= c(0.66,0.55,0.43,0.45, 0.33, 0.34,0.78, 0.31,0.89,0.87),
            stockobj=c(1,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,1))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("My app"),
    selectInput("mate", "Select material", choices = unique(df$material)),
    h3("Edit table"),
    DTOutput('x1'),
    h3("Main table"),
    DTOutput("x2")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(df=df,dfa=NULL,dfb=NULL)

    observeEvent(input$mate, {
      rv$dfa <- rv$df %>% dplyr::filter(material %in% input$mate)
      rv$dfb <- rv$df %>% dplyr::filter(!(material %in% input$mate))
    })
    
    observe({
      rv$df <- rbind(rv$dfa,rv$dfb)
      df1 <- rv$df
      newchoices <- unique(df1$material)
      selected <- input$mate
      updateSelectInput(inputId = 'mate', choices=newchoices, selected=selected)
    })

    output$x1 <- renderDT(rv$dfa, selection = 'none', rownames = F, editable = T)
    output$x2 <- renderDT({ rv$df })

    observeEvent(input$x1_cell_edit, {

      info = input$x1_cell_edit
      str(info)
      i = info$row
      j = info$col + 1  # column index offset by 1
      v = info$value
      rv$dfa[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, rv$dfa[i, j])
    })
  }
)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hi, when I run the script I get the following error:
``` 
Warning in DT::coerceValue(v, rv$df[i, j]) :
  The data type is not supported: tbl_df, tbl, data.frame
Warning: Error in : Assigned data `DT::coerceValue(v, rv$df[i, j])` must be compatible with existing data. ```

Comment: I am using DT version 0.19, and I get no error.  I will post the image of the output.

Comment: update my DT version and now it works. But the modified value is only shown in the EDIT TABLE and I would like it to also be updated in the lower table (MAIN TABLE). Any ideas?

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: It works, but when I change the filter in the upper table the values in the lower table are reset to the original values.

Comment: @ManuelVásquez , Please try the updated code.